# seq2seq - Inference model produces drastically different results than train model on the same validation set

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am working on a timeseries seq2seq problem. For my approach, I am using LSTM seq2seq RNN's with Teacher Forcing. As you already know, for the purpose of the task a model should be trained, and then using the trained layers, an inference model should be built in order to address the task (i.e. shared layers).
Here is my code for defining the shared layers:

```py
# Define the shared layers for the train and inference models
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, name='encoder_lstm')
# Define the shared layers for the train and inference models
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, name='encoder_lstm')
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, 
                    return_state=True, name='decoder_lstm')
decoder_dense = Dense(decoder_output_dim, 
                      activation='linear', name='decoder_dense')
decoder_reshape = Reshape((decoder_output_dim, ), name='decoder_reshape')
```

Next, I define the train model using the shared layers.

```py
# Define an input for the encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(Tx, encoder_input_dim), name='encoder_input')

# We discard output and keep the states only.
_, h, c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)

# Define an input for the decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(Ty, decoder_input_dim), name='decoder_input')

# Obtain all the outputs from the decoder (return_sequences = True)
decoder_outputs, _, _  = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=[h, c])

# Apply dense layer to each output
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

train_model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_outputs)
```

It is fair to mention at this point that I am using a custom loss function, which is basically Mean Square Error, but I masking certain entries.

```py
def masked_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(
                  K.mean(((y_true[:,:,0] - y_pred[:,:,0])**2)*(1-y_true[:,:,1]),
                         axis=0),
                  axis=0)
```

After training for a few epochs, the outputs are something like this:

```
Train on 67397 samples, validate on 3389 samples
Epoch 1/10
67397/67397 [==============================] - 36s 536us/sample - loss: 0.1981 - val_loss: 0.0713
Epoch 2/10
67397/67397 [==============================] - 34s 499us/sample - loss: 0.0755 - val_loss: 0.0535
Epoch 3/10
67397/67397 [==============================] - 31s 456us/sample - loss: 0.0633 - val_loss: 0.0494
Epoch 4/10
67397/67397 [==============================] - 29s 429us/sample - loss: 0.0595 - val_loss: 0.0478
```

[image: loss]

We notice that the loss for the validation set lies around **0.045**.
Now, I create the model for inference derived from the shared layers above:

```py
# Define an input for the encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(Tx, encoder_input_dim), name='encoder_input')

# We discard output and keep the states only.
_, h, c = encoder_lstm(encoder_inputs)

# Define an input for the decoder
decoder_input = Input(shape=(1, decoder_input_dim), name='decoder_input')
current_input = decoder_input

# Obtain the outputs for each of the Ty timesteps
decoder_outputs = []
for _ in range(Ty):
    # apply a single step of recurrence
    out, h, c = decoder_lstm(current_input, initial_state=[h, c])

    # pass the LSTM output through a dense layer
    out = decoder_dense(out)

    # The input in the next timestep (its shape is (?, 1, 1))
    current_input = out

    # reshape the decoder output as (?, 1) for convenience
    out = decoder_reshape(out)

    # append the output to the model's outputs
    decoder_outputs.append(out)

inference_model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_input], outputs=decoder_outputs)
```

Using this inference model, I try to evaluate it on the **same** validation set that I used during training, in order to recreate the last results:

```py
# The input for the first timestep in the decoder is -1,
# (consistently, the same was applied during training)
decoder_input = -1 * np.ones((len(X_valid), 1, 1))

# Obtain the predictions, the resulting shape is (Ty, ?, 1)
y_pred = np.array(inference_model.predict([X_valid, decoder_input]))

# Reshape the output in the shape (?, Ty, 1)
y_pred = np.swapaxes(y_pred, axis1=0, axis2=1)

loss = masked_mse(K.constant(y_valid), K.constant(y_pred))
K.eval(loss)
```

The result from evaluating the loss is **0.1637**. Continued training and it never went below 0.14.

This is very strange, since I am using the same validation set to evaluate. I suspect the error is probably somewhere in how the inference model is built, however I am not sure.
What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If your inference model has no changes from the trained model, you don't need to copy anything. You can use `train_model.predict(...)` directly on the existing model.

Copying layers is important if you are performing multiple training stages, as in transfer learning, but it is not required to use a trained model for inference.

---

But getting back to your custom loop, your LSTM recurrence should happen before the `Dense` layer is applied.

```py
decoder_outputs = []
for _ in range(Ty):
    out, h, c = decoder_lstm(current_input, initial_state=[h, c])

    # This line moved to before the decoder_dense call.
    current_input = out

    out = decoder_dense(out)
    out = decoder_reshape(out)
    decoder_outputs.append(out)
```